# What is the secrecy rate?

Tags: signal-analysis

I read several papers on physical layer security that explain several methods to maximize the secrecy rate. However, I didn't find a very clear definition about the **secrecy rate**. What is it? How is it computed?

Comment: I would suggest reading this paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1874490722000441

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pretty clear paper explaining secrecy rate and uses over fading channels.

> J. Barros and M. R. D. Rodrigues, "Secrecy Capacity of Wireless Channels," 2006 IEEE International Symposium on Information Theory, 2006, pp. 356-360, doi: 10.1109/ISIT.2006.261613.

See equation 3 for the formal definition. One way to think about it is like a tug-of-war between the main channel and wiretapping channel. If the main channel has a higher capacity then the secrecy rate is positive, otherwise it is negative.